# regular expression to remove first and last characters

Tags: regex

I am searching for regular expression to display only IP address for below string

LAN_10.100.10.41_fc3/7

I need output like below

10.100.10.41

Thanks in advance..

Comment: please add details about your input (many addresses? One per line?), tool or language which you are using, and what have you tried or how

Comment: Start from `_([^_]+)_`

Comment: i have LAN_10.100.10.41_fc3/7 text in one slot message it is just a word you can consider

Comment: Should regex consider `255.255.255.255` as valid IP and exceeding it as invalid ?

Comment: What language/tool are you using?

Comment: You can try: `^[^_]*_|_[^_]*$`

Answer (score 1):

A capture group would the simplest I think.  Something like this:

```
.+(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}).+
```

The above assumes you're using something like C++ or C# to parse and display.  Thus, displaying the result is a function of your "language".  If it's captured in an array, display it accordingly.  Sometimes it would be displayed `\1`.  You'll have to read the docs for that answer.

However, as Steven pointed out, if you're using a shell script for this and grep, then something like this should also suffice:

```
grep -o "\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}" -
```

This does assume Linux and BASH so if you're using Windows, checkout what might be accomplished with Powershell.  The `-o` says, "print only the matching portion of the line" and `-` is BASH notation for `STDIN`.  Without knowing what tools you're using for this, it's difficult to be more specific.  By the way, *the best regex testing* website I've found yet [is Regexr](http://regexr.com/).

Comment: It surpasses the `255.255.255.255`.

Comment: There's no need for the capture group at all.  Just leave the `.+` off at the beginning and then the group becomes unnecessary.

Comment: @StevenDoggart The OP didn't express in what he was doing the matching.  So I included the `.+` in the beginning to "be sure."  For example, with Boost::Regex, if you use (I believe) the `boost::regex_match()` family of functions, then the regex must *exactly match* the string whereas `boost::regex_search()` behaves more like what one is used to which `grep` or similar tools.  The capture group is specified simply because he said he wanted to display the IP address and not match it only.

Comment: Fair enough.  Point taken.  Though, if you want it to match exactly, you'd need `.+` after the group too.

Comment: @StevenDoggart ah, yes, you are quite correct.  I'll edit my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

To extract the IP address from string like this using **look around** assertions use the following regex.

**Regex**: `/(?<=._)[\d.]+(?=_.)/g`

**Explanation**:

`(?<=._)` looks for anything followed by an `_` which is appearing in pattern of your string.

`(?=_.)` looks for anything followed by `_` which is appearing in your string.

`[\d.]+` look for as many `digits` and `dots` which makes the pattern of an IP address.

It matches `LAN_`**`10.100.10.41`**`_fc3/7` only the middle part which is IP address.

**<kbd>[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pA8hS0/1)</kbd>**